# Why does retain count become 3 after allocating a view and adding it to another view?

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

Inside the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` function of my `UITableViewController`, I place a `UIActivityIndicatorView` over the selected `UITableViewCell` because tapping this cell can potentially issue a slow server request. I printed out the retain count of the `UIActivityIndicatorView` and noticed that it was 3, when I expected it to be 2.

```
// @property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
foo.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge
];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndex:indexPath];
[cell addSubView:foo.spinner];

NSLog("retain count of spinner = %d", [foo.spinner retainCount]);
```

The first retain should happen from `foo->setSpinner`. The second retain should happen from the `tableView` adding the spinner as a child view. Where is the 3rd retain? How would you avoid this memory leak?

Comment: retainCount is useless don't call it.  You are chasing ghosts and wasting your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *aSpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
foo.spinner = aSpinner;
[aSpinner release];
```

or

```
foo.spinner = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge] autorelease];
```

Everything else is fine :)

### Explanation:

Remember that synthesizing a property like:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;
```

is basically like:

```
- (void)setSpinner:(UIActivityIndicatorView *)aSpinner{
    [aSpinner retain];
    [spinner release];
    spinner = aSpinner;
}
```

So after doing
`foo.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] init...];`
retain count will be 2 (alloc/init : 1 and 2 since the property is retain). Furthermore, doing
`[someView addSubview:foo.spinner];` will increase the retain count by 1 so there you have the 3 :)

Comment: Memory management is becoming a headache. I don't understand why `foo.spinner` can possibly increment the retain count twice. I thought `@property(retain)` always releases the prior object before assigning the newer one. "Whatever goes in must go out". Shouldn't it enforce equilibrium?

Comment: Would a third option be to keep everything as I have it and just call `[foo.spinner release]` right after my first line?

Comment: It can’t, but the `-alloc` `-initEtc:` call starts the spinner out with a retain count of 1, not 0. `-release`ing it after the first line would indeed correctly balance your code.

Comment: > I don't understand why foo.spinner can possibly increment the retain count twice. It doesn't :). 

Alloc/init (before you pass to the property) is first. Then the retain (of the property) is the second. 

This process is much more easier to understand if you write like in the first example example :)

Comment: Highly recommended: [Obj-C Memory management for the lazy people] http://interfacelab.com/objective-c-memory-management-for-lazy-people/

Answer (score 6):

There is no reason for you to care what the retaincount is.  All you should concern yourself with is whether your retains and releases are  balanced.

Comment: I am expecting to remove the spinner by doing 1) `[foo.spinner removeFromSuperView]` and 2) `foo.spinner = nil`, which I'm guessing is two releases. So you see the problem here?

Comment: But you don't know how many autoreleases are pending. That's why you can't rely on the retain count this way.

Answer (score 1):

Retain count "flow":
1. First retain on `alloc`
2. Second `foo->setSpinner`
3. Third `addSubview`

Comment: Would you release right after the first property assignment to get the retain count down to 2? I'm new to iOS programming, so I would like to know what a pro would do.

Comment: This answer is at best a guess.  A reasonable guess, but a guess.  The retain count of an object from the frameworks is an internal implementation detail and the absolute value is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

## Do Not call retainCount

The absolute retain count of an object is pretty much meaningless and is often very misleading.

Think of the retain count as a delta;  you increase it, you decrease it.

So, looking at this code:

```
// @property (nonatomic, retain) UIActivityIndicatorView *spinner;

// next line is +1 for the property, +1 for the alloc
foo.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] 
    initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge
];

UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndex:indexPath];

// this line may or may not be +1;  doesn't matter. the cell is taking responsibility for
// foo.spinner and whether it retains it or copies it or ignores it is irrelevant
// (obviously, it most likely retains it, but you shouldn't care)
[cell addSubView:foo.spinner];
```

So, at the end of this, you have two retain count increments that you are responsible for.  While you could call release twice in dealloc, that'd be against pattern.   So, best to balance the +1 from alloc with a release:

```
[foo.spinner release];
```

Comment: You can consider Bill's comments on memory management as authoritative.